# Is there a method to use HSCAN (in JEDIS) to retrieve keys without values?

Tags: hash, redis, jedis

I'm using redis (with Java Redis) and I want to use a HASH with a lot of  keys and some data (binary stored) in each key
I want to iterate by the keys of the map, while not blocking the server; because a lot of processes access this server.

Because of this, I don't want to use the HKEYS command.
And I would like to use the HSCAN command, or a similar method. Because I only want the keys in this step of my operations.

But as the documentation explains, the HSCAN method returns:
- The cursor
- An array of pair of key-values
*(see [scan](https://redis.io/commands/scan), and [hscan](https://redis.io/commands/hscan) (not many info, and refers to the last link ))*

As I said, I want to recieve only the keys; not the values. But the HSCAN method returns both, and I'm afraid it can hurt the performance of the server and my application.

I've been searching the documentation and forums, and found no response. But if anyone knows better, please let me know.

*It bugs me a little to know that SCAN method works like I want but HSCAN not.... wonder why.*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `HSCAN` indeed returns the field-value pairs in a Hash, you can transform the output to filter the values with a server-side Lua script (see the [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval) for details). This will reduce the network usage and client-side load, at the price of making the server work (a little) harder.

The following script provides a possible implementation:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local cursor = ARGV[1]
local res = redis.call('HSCAN', key, cursor)
local rep = { res[1], {} }
for i=1, #res[2], 2 do
  table.insert(rep[2], res[2][i])
end
return rep
```

Comment: Ok, I do not know lua, but I think you filter the response by creating a new result with the cursor and a array of keys.     
      
Should not be table.insert(rep[2], res[2][i][0]) or similar to only have the key ?

Comment: Lua is (I think) easy to read and you understood most of it correctly. Note that res[2] is an array of alternating fields and values from the Hash. The loop starts at index 1 (Lua is 1-based) and iterates with step of 2. This results in copying only the field names to the rep(ly). BTW - I tested that snippet and it appears to be working correctly ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. See you!